# Why is the following program deadlock?

Tags: go

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    c <- 5
    a := <- c
    fmt.Println(a)
 }
```

Here both the data is being sent and recieved to/from the channel but still the error is being displayed:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channel is unbuffered. So if one writes to it - and no other goroutine is reading from it - it is a guaranteed deadlock.

To fix, either make it unbuffered:

```
c := make(chan int, 1)
```

or write asynchronously from another goroutine:

```
go func() {
    c <- 5
}()
```

https://play.golang.org/p/RRJILbuZKTQ

---

Since channels are used to communicate between goroutines, its extremely rare one writes to a channel from the same goroutine as the reads. An exception may be, if using a channel as a resource pool and one wants to pre-populate the (buffered) channel.

Comment: I totally support second option. Using buffered channels to fix wrong concurrent patterns will mislead you.

Answer (score 2):

Your channel `c` doesn't have any buffer (even a single cell), which means that the main goroutine locks at the `c <- 5` line. Since it is the only goroutine in your application, it creates a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Channels make(chan int) has implicit size zero ( ref: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)

A channel of size zero is unbuffered. A channel of specified size make(chan int, n) is buffered. See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Send_statements for a discussion on buffered vs. unbuffered channels. The example at http://play.golang.org/p/VZAiN1V8-P illustrates the difference.

Here, channel <-c or c <- will be blocked until someone processes it (concurrently). So, change c := make(chan int) to c := make(chan int,1)

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
   c := make(chan int, 1)
   c <- 5
   a := <- c
   fmt.Println(a)
 }
```